# How to increase monk's chance to land a Stunning Strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, saving-throw, unearthed-arcana, advantage-and-disadvantage

My monk is a multi-class character (Monk 9/Paladin 8) in a homebrew 5e campaign and clearly does not have too many ki points as level 17 character. I also find it inconsiderate and boring when burning through ki points in just a few rounds to attempt to stun a monster (which is even more challenging with Legendary Resistances).

**What spells, feats, skills, class features, etc. can help monk to successfully perform a stunning strike?**  (5e and Unearthed Arcana)

---

Some solutions I am aware of after extensive research:

1. Increase monk's wisdom ability score

   - Feats: Resilient, Observant, Prodigy (UA), etc.
   - Items: Tome of Understanding, Ioun Stone, Book of Exalted Deeds. Maybe more?
   - Spells: Wish. Maybe more? Any way to temporarily increase WIS?
2. Negatively affect target's Constitution Saving throw:

   - Spells: Bane, Bestow Curse, Contagion, Glyph of Warding (indirectly). Maybe more?
   - Class Abilities: Wizard's Portent, Sorcerer's Bend Luck. Maybe more?
   - Items: Nothing in 5e and UA?
   - Other: [Inflict exhaustion condition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112433/are-there-any-ways-to-force-levels-of-exhaustion-onto-another-creature)  level 3, make monster own a treasure from a Mummy Lord's Lair. Maybe more?

Comment: FYI, Prodigy was released officially in XGE, and it no longer includes the attribute boost.

Comment: I'd consider restricting against UA, as there could be some confusion between things that were once UA, but now officially published, such as Prodigy.

Comment: Are you looking for solutions that for your character alone? Are you willing to dip for the final three levels of your build or should it be optimized for your current multiclass? Are you looking, and is your party interested in, helping you achieve this (i.e. will they use their resources/action economy to increase your chances?) If so, what classes are they and what spells do they currently have?

Comment: What other classes are in the party? Perhaps your allies could support your character's effectiveness, or conversely, you can assist them with more reliable tactics than Stunning Strike?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I'd rather have a list of all possible options, not just for my current character. Seems like @Someone_Evil already covered everything below.
Thank you everyone for clarifying things!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll cover things again, so as to try to get a single, complete list, and because I think there are some additional points to mention. I make the split into two categories:

Buffing your own save DC:

- Improving your wisdom score up to 20:

  - Ability score improvements
  - Feats: Resilient, Observant, Elven Accuracy (XGtE; Elves, half-elves)
  - Ioun stone of Insight
- Improving your Wisdom score beyond 20:

  - Book of Exhalted Deeds (upto 24)
  - Tome of Understanding (up to the innate max of 30)
  - Deck of Many Things: Star (upto 24) (pull cards from the deck at your own risk)
- Increasing your proficiency bonus

  - Ioun stone of Mastery (+1)

Weakening the target's constitution save:

- Negative modifier

  - *Bane* (1d4)
  - Wild Magic Sorcerer's Bend Luck (1d4)
  - *Mind Sliver* (1d4; TCoE), thanks to Jesse Quimby for pointing this out
- Disadvantage:

  - *Bestow Curse*
  - *Sickening Radiance* (through granting exhaustion)
  - Staff of Withering
  - Claw of the Wyrm Rune's Wyrm Ward (Storm Kings Thunder; Consumes the item, requires 8h prep work on the area, and only works on dragons)
- Replacing the roll through Wizard School of Divination's Portent

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought that Ioun Stone of Mastery affects only skills proficiency bonuses, but clearly it is much more powerful than that. I guess it is for balancing reasons that so few spells/abilities can affect monster's CON saving throws.