# What spells, items, and abilities improve wisdom ability checks?

Tags: dnd-5e

My level 3 cleric is trying to cast a level 5 spell-scroll, and to optimize the chances of success, I want to stack as many positive ability check buffs on him as possible. Preferrably lower-level/easy to access ones. So far I have:

- Enhance Ability (Wisdom)
- Bardic Inspiration
- Guidance
- Portent (Divination Wizard)

I'm sure I'm missing a ton.

Comment: Do you actually have access to these things in your party or at your table? While a list can be made for things that improve Wisdom ability checks, if they're not actually available I'm not sure they'll be useful to you. And if you can use a portent, why do you need anything else?

Comment: I'm playing in a large, online, Westmarches style campaign with 30+ players and easily 100+ characters. I don't know fully what's available and what's not. On the topic of portent specifically, it's sort of nerfed in this game: short rests are overnight and long rests are a week. We'd only likely have one shot at using portent dice.

Comment: If you've got additional requirements (like not depending on a 3rd party), that would be good to add. You should the rules variant you are using, though. But ultimately, there is a difference between "what things can improve my chances" and "what would make sense to use in the specific case of this particular table/ruleset". Can you buy any magic at any time? Do you want only things that you can do? Are the other players willing to use their limited resources to assist you? etc.

Comment: I don't really have additional requirements. My plan was to look at this list, then pick and choose what would work for me and my campaign. As opposed to querying a list that would help me and only me, this list could be useful to others playing in different games with different rules.

Comment: Very related on [What is the maximum possible stealth bonus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156899) and [What is the highest total result one can get for a skill check?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144371)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check those out.

Comment: You also may find this a bit helpful: "[How to increase monk's chance to land a Stunning Strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164683)"

Comment: Thanks. Some good stuff in there for sure.